# Update Trigger in mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers

I need to create an after update trigger which fills a new table with 
the previous value in lowercase, the new value in uppercase, the user who made the statement, the full date, and the character difference between the two text strings.
The problem is that before i created the trigger everything was working normally if i was doing any update, but now after i created the trigger and i tried to make an update it doesn't shows an error and everything goes green but none rows is affected. These are the tables and the trigger i've created.

```
CREATE TABLE product 
 (id_product VARCHAR (25) primary key,
 name VARCHAR (50) not null,
 stock enum('Not avaliable','Avaliable') not null,
 description VARCHAR (300) default ('N/A'),
 price decimal (5,2) not null,
 category_code VARCHAR (25),
 foreign key (category_code ) references category (category_code )
 ) ENGINE=INNODB;



INSERT INTO product values ('CS1232', 'Death Stranding','avaliable', 'Death Stranding is an open world exploration and action 
video game developed by Kojima Productions 
and published by Sony Interactive 
Entertainment for PlayStation 4 and by 505 Games for Microsoft Windows.', '30.50', 'VD' );

create table strings
( date DATE PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT NOW(), 
lowercase_value VARCHAR (50) , 
uppercase_value VARCHAR (50), 
user VARCHAR (50), 
difference int
)engine=innodb;

DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER update_AU after update on product for each row 
begin 
INSERT INTO strings (lowercase_value , 
uppercase_value, user, difference) values (lower(OLD.id_product), upper(new.id_product), 
current_user(), ABS(length(old.id_product) - length(new.id_product)));
end // 
DELIMITER ; 

UPDATE product set id_product = 'CSWURE' WHERE id_product = 'CS1232';

Once i do this update it just go green and say: 0 row(s) affected Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0  0.000 sec
```

Comment: Examples please

Comment: you are trying to insert 5 values on 4 columns to your trigger. Delete `current_timestamp()` from your `INSERT`.

Comment: Not `lower(OLD.id_product.product)` but `lower(OLD.id_product)`

Comment: I just edited it and it stills not working. I added some insert and update examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER update_AU 
AFTER UPDATE 
ON product 
FOR EACH ROW 
INSERT INTO strings (lowercase_value , 
                     uppercase_value, 
                     user, 
                     difference) 
    VALUES (LOWER(OLD.id_product), 
            UPPER(NEW.id_product), 
            CURRENT_USER(), 
            ABS(LENGTH(OLD.id_product) - LENGTH(NEW.id_product)));
```

[fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bNGpNWQ5M1APpz7YCNzpiW/0)

Pay attention to the editions made in table definitions.

Comment: If i'm not wrong u changed upper, lower, current_user and length to uppercase. I tried using it but still not working. Don't know why it just keeps not affecting rows but still not throwing an error.

Comment: I just realised the default date was wrong, i changed it to default current_timestamp  and now it is working perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: I have added that you must *Pay attention to the editions made in table definitions* specially...